# When Window Size Is Smaller Elements Overlap Eachother?

Tags: css, scrollbar, resolution, overlap

I have designed a website and am a little bit stumped right now.

If you view the website at:

http://www.noxinnovations.com/portfolio/charidimos/

If you change the size of the window you will notice the Navigation overlaps the logo/header.

Anyway to change this? What I want to do virtually is to make the window have a scroll bar appear if that is possible.

Any ideas?

Thank you :-D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your `width: 100%;` in your `#header` element that's causing your strange overflow behavior. Place your `#logo` and `#navigation` elements inside of another `div` with a fixed height and width that sits inside of the `#header`, then give your `#header` the property `overflow: hidden;` and that should fix you right up.

Comment: But will this still have the background-image of the header to repeat-x 100% throughout the window?

Comment: Yeah... You can pretty much keep the rest of your `#header` css the same; you just need a new wrapper element inside of `#header` that has a fixed width.

Comment: Okay, I have re-uploaded it, please do a cache-refresh and or a browser refresh. As you can tell. When the resolution is smaller it does shrink, but every element shrinks which puts everything out of place. What I want to do is have to where if the resolution is too small that the scrollbar must appear so they can scroll and view everything. Know what I am saying? Thank you.

Comment: Everything is overlapping now because you removed your floats and positioned your `#logo` and `#navigation` absolute. Go back to `position: relative` and float your two elements left and right again.

Comment: Also, if my math is right, change `width: 100%` on your `#header-container` element to `width: 1276px`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your navigation not to overlap, you can do the following

```
#navigation {
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
padding-top: 52px;
position: fixed;    // CHANGE FROM RELATIVE TO FIXED
left: 770px;        // ADD THIS BIT OF POSITIONING (ADJUST AS NECESSARY)
float: right;       //REMOVE THIS FLOAT
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;

}
```